# Serving uncompiled versions of assets in rails 3.1+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, dart

I am currently working on an integration of Dart into the Rails Asset Pipeline.

Compilation is already working; `.dart` files are compiled into `.js` by the Asset Pipeline. However, there should also be an uncompiled `.dart` version that can be interpreted by Dartium.

The usual way is that `.dart` files are included in the html source with a type of `"application/dart"`. Then there's [dart.js](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/trunk/dart/client/dart.js), which replaces those `.dart` files with the corresponding `.js` version if the browser doesn't understand Dart, replacding `foo.dart` with `foo.dart.js`.

My problem is, that the asset pipeline is serving the compiled JavaScript version, even if the client requests `foo.dart`. `foo.dart` should serve the original, uncompiled version, only `foo.dart.js` should be compiled.

Source for [ruby-dart](https://github.com/amiuhle/ruby-dart) and 
[dart-rails](https://github.com/amiuhle/dart-rails)

**Edit**: I thought about just copying the raw `.dart` files to the public folder, but that's not an option, since the source file that is seen by the Asset Pipeline might include other `.dart` files, which are then compiled into one single `.js` file. So, not all `.dart` files would be copied.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't worked on that for ages...

Answer (score 1):

you can put your .dart files directly in public/assets/

You should only put assets you want to pre-process into app/assets/ (or vendor/assets/... etc.). The assets that you don't want pre-processed, can be put directly in public/assets/ folder

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if it might be easier to skip the asset pipeline altogether and rely on Dart editor to compile your JavaScript whenever you're happy with your code. Sorry, I know that's a bit ghetto.